# Принимаемые значения функции в питоне?

Tags: python-3.x, namespace

Задался вопросом: есть ли смысл передавать в функцию те значения, которые определены в вышестоящем неймспейсе? Типа так:

```
def some_foo_foo(var)
    pass


def some_foo():
    var = 5
    some_foo_foo(var)
```

Или не передавать, ведь питон, не найдя переменную в локальном неймспейсе, пойдет выше? Я в питоне человек новый, поэтому заранее извиняюсь за примитив.

Comment: У вас в «вышестоящем неймспейсе» определены только две функции `some_foo_foo` и `some_foo`. Переменная `var` находится внутри локального неймспейса функции и никогда не будет винда из других мест (кроме случая создания замыкания)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере контексты не пересекаются, иначе передавать необязательно

```py
def some_foo():
    def some_foo_foo():
        print(var) # 5

    var = 5
    some_foo_foo()

some_foo()
```

Но есть моменты, о которых не стоит забывать:

1. При присваивании внутри вложенной функции создается собственная копия переменной, если только она не помечена как `global` или `nonlocal`

```py
def foo():
    def bar():
        nonlocal var2
        var1 = var2 = 6

    var1 = var2 = 5
    bar()
    print(var1, var2) # 5 6

foo()
```

2. Эта копия создается в самом начале выполнения функции, даже если присвоение приозойдет позже. До этого момента попытка чтения переменной приведет к ошибке.

```py
def foo():
    def bar():
        print(var) # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment
        var = 6

    var = 5
    bar()

foo()
```

3. Не важно когда объявлена переменная вышестоящего контекста, во вложенной функции будет использовано актуальное на момент вызова значение.

```py
def foo():
    var = 5

    def f():
        print(var)

    var = 6

    def g():
        print(var)

    return f, g

f, g = foo()
f() # 6
g() # 6
```